# Golang record ids are 0

Tags: postgresql, go

I have the following **Car** model and a **cars** slice:

```
type Car struct {
    ID     int    `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"title"`
}

var cars []Car
```

On a Postgres database, I have created a **cars** table to save **car** records.

```
create table cars (id serial, name varchar);
```

And saved, a couple of **car** records:

```
insert into cars (name) values ('Toyota');
insert into cars (name) values ('Lexus');
```

The records are created successfully with incremental integer ids 1 and 2.

In my Go server, I am making the following query to get the car records:

```
db.Query("SELECT * from cars").Rows(&cars)

for _, car := range cars {
    fmt.Println(car)
}
```

Although there is a response, the id for each record comes as 0. I have tried to find out why, but I was not able to. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`database/sql` package does not provide to scan the data directly to a struct, you should iterate over the rows returned from the database query and then scan the data into struct as:

```
var cars []cars
for rows.Next() {
        var car cars
        err = rows.Scan(&c.ID, &c.Name)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Scan: %v", err)
        }
        cars = append(cars, car)
}
fmt.Println(cars)
```

Or you can use extension for sql package name [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) which will provide you to directly scan the result into the slice of struct as:

```
cars := []cars{}
db.Select(&cars, "SELECT * from cars")
```